# Magento create personal coupon to newsletter

Tags: magento, newsletter, coupon

With Magento version 1.7, how can I auto generate a personal 10% discount coupon for each newsletter receiver that can only be used once by that specific account/user?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an idea. Actually 2 of them.

The quick one.
Create a coupon with your desired rules, set the number of uses to 1 per customer and unlimited for general usage and hard code the coupon code in the newsletter email.
Estimated time: 30 minutes including tests. Risk: minimum.

The slow but clean one:
Create an observer on the `newsletter_subscriber_save_before` or `newsletter_subscriber_save_after` that checks if the customer subscribes and if so, it creates a coupon with your desired settings. [See this for creating coupons by code](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.com/2010/04/create-bulk-discount-rules.html).
Then rewrite the method `Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::sendConfirmationSuccessEmail` so you can pass that code as a parameter to the e-mail template.
Something like this:

```
$email->sendTransactional(
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY),
        $this->getEmail(),
        $this->getName(),
        array('subscriber'=>$this, 'coupon_code'=>THE COUPON GENERATED IN THE EVENT)
    );
```

Then modify the newsletter subscription e-mail template to include this:

```
Your coupon code is: {{var coupon_code}}
```

Estimate 4h-8h. Risk: "not that minimum".

I would take the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use personal discount extension http://www.magalter.com/personal-discount.html to generate 10% discount coupon. You will be able to choose customers who can use this coupon.